# Azure Blob Storage - Get Blob by Tags is not working

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have been experiencing issues with the Get By Tags functionality for the Azure Blob REST Api.

I am trying to add and read tags from blobs but when requesting from the url via postman on the url that is similar to -
https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/myblob?comp=tags , I get the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:92580002-101e-001c-7af7-76bf3e000000
Time:2020-08-20T13:42:08.8566047Z</Message>
    <QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName>
    <QueryParameterValue>tags</QueryParameterValue>
    <Reason />
</Error>
```

Comment: Can you please let us know which rest api you are using? [Find Blobs by Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/find-blobs-by-tags) or [Get Blob Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-tags)?

Comment: which api are you using? can you provide a link? And for tags, it's a new feature for blob storage, currently, it has some limitations.

Comment: The [Find Blob by Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/find-blobs-by-tags) API

Comment: can you set the tags for a blob via Azure portal? As far as I know, the tag feature is currently in preview, and only supports a few regions.

Comment: Nope ...have to set it as part of the signature as a "t" in the permissions parameter. But even that does not work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#blob-sas this is the documentation

Comment: you should see this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#regional-availability-and-storage-account-support), for the supported region, and how to register the new feature.

Comment: Yip seems like I need to read a bit more ...Tx Ivan

Comment: Hello, I just added an answer. If it's helpful, please accept it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks:).

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature for blob. This feature is now **in preview** and only supports the following regions:

1. Canada Central
2. Canada East
3. France Central
4. France South

Because this feature is only in public preview, you'll need to register your subscription before you can use the feature. Read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal) for more details.

Comment: Are all APIs related to tags in preview or just getBlobByTags ?